# Polymer 1.0 How to vertical menu

Tags: menu, polymer

m-layout code:

```
<style>
    paper-item{
        background-color: #EBEBEB;
        width : 100%;
        padding:20px;
        color : #252525;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: "RobotoDraft",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
          font-weight: 300;
          line-height: 24px;
    }
</style>

<dom-module id="m-layout" >
<template>
    <!-- Drawer Menu -->
    <paper-drawer-panel>
      <paper-header-panel navigation flex drawer style="background-color : #EBEBEB">
        <paper-material elevation="1">
            <paper-toolbar style="color : #252525; background-color : #EBEBEB;" >
              <div flex style="text-align: center;">ID</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
        </paper-material>

        <!-- Menu -->
        <div vertical layout style="height:400px" >
          <paper-menu>
            <paper-item>Notice</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Lecture</paper-item>
          </paper-menu>      
        </div>
      </paper-header-panel>

    <!-- Main -->
    <paper-header-panel main>
      <paper-toolbar style="background-color : #259DFF">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" style="color: white;" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
         <div>Title</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
      <div style ="padding:20px; color : #252525;"> Main content... </div>
    </paper-header-panel>

   </paper-drawer-panel>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

I want vertical drawer menu but width attribute in paper-item is not apply. 
And I apply vertical layout in Menu ...
I tried to continue but fail....  drawer menu item is located horizontal..

It is the first time to Web study & Polymer.... I understand some attibute..
What should I do to make vertical menu?

Comment: Put the `style` tag inside the `dom-module`. Also, layout attributes (like `flex`, `vertical`, `center`, etc.) are no longer present in Polymer 1.0. Try using [Custom CSS Properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details) instead.

Comment: To use the CSS properties that are related to the previously available attributes, try looking at [iron-flex-layout](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout).